# Import Error( cannot import name contactForm )

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to build an e_commerc django app, but I have encounter an Error, and It is little confusing.
Mine error is:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.7.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'profiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/petarp/Documents/Udemy/Learn_Django/static/templates/navbar.html, error at line 15
   cannot import name contactForm
   5 :           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> 
   6 :             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
   7 :             <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   8 :             <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   9 :             <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   10 :           </button> 
   11 :           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a> 
   12 :         </div> 
   13 :         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
   14 :           <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
   15 :             {% url 'home' as home %}  
   16 :            {% url 'about' as about %}


   17 :            {% url 'contact' as contact %} 
   18 :             <li {% if request.path == home %} class="active" {%endif%}><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li> 
   19 :             <li {% if request.path == about %} class="active" {%endif%}><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li> 
   20 :             <li {% if request.path == contact %} class="active" {%endif%}><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li> 
   21 :             <li class="dropdown"> 
   22 :               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a> 
   23 :               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
   24 :                 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li> 
   25 :                 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li> 
Traceback:
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/petarp/Documents/Udemy/Learn_Django/source/profiles/views.py" in home
  7.     return render(request, tempalte, context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  50.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  178.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.                 return template.render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  444.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  551.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  415.             self._populate()
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  303.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  231.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py" in wrapper
  101.                     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/e_udemy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/petarp/Documents/Udemy/Learn_Django/source/contact/views.py" in <module>
  3. from .forms import contactForm

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name contactForm
```

I do not understand this error, or better to say I can not see this error. This are mine [views.py](http://ur1.ca/jqs6x) and [forms.py](http://ur1.ca/jqs7m). How come he can not import contactForm?
Can someone explain to how can I overcome this.
Tank you.

Comment: your form.py file is in the same dir that views.py ?

Comment: Why you using `.forms` in import statement -  `from .forms import contactForm`. That could be the cause.

Comment: @Rohan .forms  its fine,it refers to local forms module. The question is if his forms.py file is in the same dir that views.py.

Comment: if you used `contactForm` in your template by **contactForm** name you must  change these used names in your templates to **form**.

    {{ form }}  # <--- old name was contactForm

Comment: @levi, Yes mine forms.py and views.py are part of mine contact app. They are in the same directory

Comment: @PetarPilipovic are u trying to use contactForm in your template?

Comment: I forgot to link mine [contact.html](http://ur1.ca/jqsdy), this is where I am trying to use mine contactForm.

Comment: Check out other views.py and urls.py (other python files) that are using `ContactForm`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made a mistake in forms.py.

Please make sure that you have spelled the `contactForm` function correctly. In the `contactForm`, the `F` must be capitalized.

```
class contactForm(forms.Form):
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `contactForm` in your template, but you didn't pass it. So in your view,

```
def contact(request):
    form = contactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print request.POST
        #remember save your form. 
    context = {'contactForm':form}
    template = 'contact.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

In your template,you can use

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form method="POST" action="" > {% csrf_token %}
    {{ contactForm.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="submit form" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Tank you for this, but bad news is, the error is still there. He can not import it and he is pointing to the navbar.html line 15.

Comment: it this your navbar.html line 15 {% url 'home' as home %} ?

Comment: can you see mine navbar.html?

Comment: I have solved this whit absolute import, tank you for your help. Sorry if I was confusing in mine post. Tank you for helping me.